# Return address of the first frame in stack

Tags: java, multithreading, process, jvm, stack

When a thread executes its `return` instruction we say that the thread is finished. For me this has to do with the execution stack. At the moment when the thread reaches the `return` instruction there is one frame in the stack, and when it calls `return`, it will attempt to jump to the return address stored in this first frame.

So my questions are:

- What is the content of the return address of the first frame ?
- If it does contain a concrete instruction address, then what is this next instruction ?
- If it does not, then how the cpu jumps to an instruction address that doesn't exist ?

For all these questions I am assuming that the main routine of a process/thread contains a jump address instruction at the end. If this is not the case, how the OS knows the process has executed its last instruction? I mean the cpu is always incrementing its PC and if the OS does not terminate the process, PC will point to an invalid address.

Comment: A common approach is, when creating the thread, to 'preload' the stack with the address of a stub that calls a 'TerminateThread()' API.  The OS has to set up the thread stack anyway, just to start it, so it's easy to shove on the stub return.

Comment: @MartinJames could you please give the OS that does that and any useful links ?